# NGINX Ingress Controller UDP Load Balancing Packet Drops

Tags: kubernetes, udp, performance-testing, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I am performing PT or Load testing activity on our application pods for **UDP** traffic in Kubernetes cluster. The load first comes to NGINX Ingress Controller pod and then it gets forwarded to application pods.

If I send the traffic to directly my pods, it is able to handle traffic of 70k tps. But If I send the same traffic via NGINX, the packet drops don't happen at application. But it happen at NGINX level.

I tried to take the reference from below links, but nothing helped.
https://gist.github.com/v0lkan/90fcb83c86918732b894
https://gist.github.com/denji/8359866

Config used, removed the HTTP Block

```
# Configuration checksum: 13343735496899811162

# setup custom paths that do not require root access
pid /tmp/nginx/nginx.pid;

daemon off;

worker_processes 5;

worker_rlimit_nofile 1047552;

worker_shutdown_timeout 240s ;

events {
        multi_accept        on;
        worker_connections  16384;
        use                 epoll;

}

stream {
        lua_package_path "/etc/nginx/lua/?.lua;/etc/nginx/lua/vendor/?.lua;;";

        lua_shared_dict tcp_udp_configuration_data 5M;

        init_by_lua_block {
                collectgarbage("collect")

                -- init modules
                local ok, res

                ok, res = pcall(require, "configuration")
                if not ok then
                error("require failed: " .. tostring(res))
                else
                configuration = res
                end

                ok, res = pcall(require, "tcp_udp_configuration")
                if not ok then
                error("require failed: " .. tostring(res))
                else
                tcp_udp_configuration = res
                tcp_udp_configuration.prohibited_localhost_port = '10246'

                end

                ok, res = pcall(require, "tcp_udp_balancer")
                if not ok then
                error("require failed: " .. tostring(res))
                else
                tcp_udp_balancer = res
                end
        }

        init_worker_by_lua_block {
                tcp_udp_balancer.init_worker()
        }

        lua_add_variable $proxy_upstream_name;

        log_format log_stream '[$remote_addr] [$time_local] $protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received $session_time';

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log log_stream ;

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

        upstream upstream_balancer {
                server 0.0.0.1:1234; # placeholder

                balancer_by_lua_block {
                        tcp_udp_balancer.balance()
                }
        }

        server {
                listen 127.0.0.1:10247;

                access_log off;

                content_by_lua_block {
                        tcp_udp_configuration.call()
                }
        }

        # TCP services

        # UDP services

        server {
                preread_by_lua_block {
                        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="udp-cgnat-cgnat-app-2232";
                }

                listen                  2200 udp;

                listen                  [::]:2200 udp;

                proxy_responses         1;
                proxy_timeout           600s;
                proxy_next_upstream     on;
                proxy_next_upstream_timeout 600s;
                proxy_next_upstream_tries   3;
                proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
        }

        server {
                preread_by_lua_block {
                        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="udp-cgnat-cgnat-app-2233";
                }

                listen                  2201 udp;

                listen                  [::]:2201 udp;

                proxy_responses         1;
                proxy_timeout           600s;
                proxy_next_upstream     on;
                proxy_next_upstream_timeout 600s;
                proxy_next_upstream_tries   3;
                proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
        }

        server {
                preread_by_lua_block {
                        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="udp-cgnat-cgnat-app-2234";
                }

                listen                  2202 udp;

                listen                  [::]:2202 udp;

                proxy_responses         1;
                proxy_timeout           600s;
                proxy_next_upstream     on;
                proxy_next_upstream_timeout 600s;
                proxy_next_upstream_tries   3;
                proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
        }

        server {
                preread_by_lua_block {
                        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="udp-cgnat-cgnat-app-2235";
                }

                listen                  2203 udp;

                listen                  [::]:2203 udp;

                proxy_responses         1;
                proxy_timeout           600s;
                proxy_next_upstream     on;
                proxy_next_upstream_timeout 600s;
                proxy_next_upstream_tries   3;
                proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
        }

        # Stream Snippets

}
```

`vCPU: 5`

`Memory: 20GB`

This is the generated nginx conf inside nginx pod.

Are there any parameters that I should change for better performance.

The testing is being done for UDP traffic only.

Following is the NGINX ingress controller that we are using, https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/

Also let me know if there is any other UDP load balancer that I should try which has better performance.